# How do I ignore every input after the first few characters in the console in C#?

Tags: c#, string, object, parsing, console

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var information= Console.ReadLine();
            var one= Int32.Parse(informatie.Split(' ')[0]);
            var two = Int32.Parse(informatie.Split(' ')[1]);
        }
    }
```

I want the user to input the following: two numbers, seperated by a whitespace, so, for example: 5 2

After that, I want to be able to catch the first number in var one and the second one in var two. How can I make this program such that everything which comes after the 2 will be ignored? Right now, if I add anything else after the 2, the program crashes.

Comment: That's probalby because the code: 1) Assumes there will be a second index in the array returned from `Split` and 2) is blindly trying to parse the string to an `int`. Instead, you can use a loop to "walk" though each character of the string. Then you can do whatever you want based on the actual value of the character.

Comment: Are you only interested in the first three characters of the string, or can the numbers be larger than one character, possibly separated by more than one space?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the characters by index, then use `Char.GetNumericValue` to convert to `int`:

```
var one = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(informatie[0]);
var two = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(informatie[2]);
```

Of course you should also validate the input.